# How do I create a interval of 7 days without 'w','week' or 'WeekOfYear'?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, reporting-services, parameters, bids

I am trying to sort data by the week it was created. I can not use `'w'` in `DateAdd`, `'week'` or `'WeekOfYear'` without an error stating that function/expression is inaccessible.

What is the best way to create a substitute expression? I want the expression to group the dates based on the week it was created.

I am trying to replicate this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6t8A.jpg

Comment: Do you need to sort or group by calculated weeks?. I am suspecting your issue is related to grouping not to calculate weeks. Share an example of your dataset, and the expected tabilx, matrix or component you want to show in order to we can help you

Comment: Sorry - I need to group by calculated weeks. My dataset contains a created on field and I want to group the entities based on the week they were created. I want to show a column that contains the "Week ending in <date of friday that week>" with the column containing the expression that would group the dates by week and show the date of that friday.

Comment: I have a sketch of what you need but I am not sure, you should update your question and add sample dataset and expected result.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I updated the question with a link to an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected results you posted in the edition of your question I have reproduced the tablix.

I've used the following dataset:

[image]

I am supposing you are going to use a `tablix` component so I added this one with the following data arrangement.

[image]

In the `Row Groups` panel right click on `date` group.

[image]

In group properties, add a group expression and set this:

`=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!date.Value),Fields!date.Value)`

Also in the tablix you have to set the same expression:

[image]

In the columns you want to sum you can use the Sum function or any aggregation function. I've used `=Sum(Fields!value.Value)` to Sum values within the same week.

This is the result it will preview:

Let me know if this was helpful.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But when I create a grouping based on  "=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!date.Value),Fields!date.Value)" I receive the error "The GroupExpression expression for the tablix 'table1' contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of 'Public Function Day(DateValue As Date) As Integer'. 


The only edit i made to the above code was adding my field name in. So it reads "=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!createdon.Value),Fields!createdon.Value)"

Comment: How your query is retrieving date? `varchar` or `date` type? I think it is a problem with your datasource. Try to convert the date column to a proper `date` type.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to check that. I'm very new to reporting services

Comment: For test delete all expressions `=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Fields!date.Value),Fields!date.Val‌​ue)` occurrences and in any cell of the tablix put this: `=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Today()),Today())`. Tell me if the error persists

Comment: Okay i deleted the previous expression and added "=DATEADD("d",7-DATEPART(DateInterval.Weekday,Today()),Today())" to a cell in the tablix. I am still receiving the error.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted every occurence of the previous expression? I'd create a new report or even better a new project and try it again. I am not sure if the error is related to my answer, but I don't discard a setup issue with your environment. Again, be sure you deleted all expression and just leave the test expression.

Comment: Okay I created a new report and the test expression works without an error